# When i try to build apk(s) on android studio 3 it gives me error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, opencv, android-ndk

I'm trying to make LPR app on android studio. I'm using OpenCV 3.1.0 and Tesseract for recognition and when i try to build apk it gives me this

> Error: Flag android.useDeprecatedNdk is no longer supported and will be 
>    removed in the next version of Android Studio.  Please switch to a supported 
>    build system.
>    Consider using CMake or ndk-build integration. For more information, go to:
>     https://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/add-native-code.html#ndkCompile
>     To get started, you can use the sample ndk-build script the Android
>     plugin generated for you at:
>     C:\Users\m\Desktop\TestTmp\LPR\app\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\Android.mk
>    Alternatively, you can use the experimental plugin:
>     https://developer.android.com/r/tools/experimental-plugin.html
>    To continue using the deprecated NDK compile for another 60 days, set 
>    android.deprecatedNdkCompileLease=1510879276001 in gradle.properties

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: How to remove this error? I want to build apk.

Comment: The message you quoted already tells you what to do.

Comment: Then when i type in that 1 line of code it still give me that error with new generated integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you still want to use deprecated NDK version add following into your `gradle.properties`

```
android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

you will be able to build the project and APK file.

Answer (score 2):

AndroidStudio 3.0

`// Remove this line
android.useDeprecatedNdk = true`

you can get more detail by:
https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code?utm_source=android-studio#ndkCompile